# Display on axes at GUI (matlab)

Tags: image, matlab

I have some problems cause matlab doing things on his own will. 
When I Run the code above (just running the script file alone)  I Get the proper result.

```
A=imread('ct.png');
B=imread('mri.png');



A=double(A);
B=double(B);


C = wfusmat(A,B,'max')


imshow(subplot(221));
subplot(221),image(A),axis square,Title('Image1')
subplot(222),image(B),axis square,Title('Image2')
subplot(223),image(C),axis square,Title('Fused Image')
```

Though when I try to run in the UI file this code:

```
A=imread('ct.png');
B=imread('mri.png');


A=double(A);
B=double(B);



C = wfusmat(A,B,'max');

axes(handles.axes3);
imshow(C);
```

The result I get is like a distorted image with many many white pixels.Actually you can't see nothing.

Any ideas why that's happening? I guess that since the code runs in a single script correctly it should do the same as well when it runs inside the UI main script....

Answer (score 0):

The command `imread` returns values between 0 and 255.
In the first example you used `image` to display the images which accepts the same range of values.
However, in the second example, you used the command `imshow` that accepts values between 0 and 1. In that case, values greater than 1 are displayed as white which explains the many white pixels you see.